# Pentaho Report Designer 5.0.1 and MySQL 8.0 is not working

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to connect mysql 8.0 in Pentaho report designer 5.0 and also added mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar in report-designer\lib\jdbc path.

no connection, showing error :

```
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Could not create connection to database server.
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the tools of pentaho is having limitation you have to use correct drivers,correct jdk according to the pentaho version you are using.

Mysql 8 even does not work with pentaho report designer 8.2 or other tools of pentaho with latest release.

please downgrade your mysql connector in order to connect to server.